# Set VAT fields in customer registration with checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, vat

I want to fill all the VAT fields of a customer after the customer registers ( i guess an event that i can hook into). But i need to know how i can manually get the VAT value the customer fills in and save it in all the other VAT fields (like user details etc)

Comment: You mean Vat ID?

Comment: you can use `customer_register_success` event observer

Comment: That event is good to hook into, if a vat id is needed for the other fields to save the vat value then yes. But how can i make sure that one vat value is saved in the other vat fields, like address and customer information and stuff After registration? Can somebody make an example, would be a life saver.